# Is it possible to set up SVN to check out certain files only on certain operating systems?

Tags: svn, cross-platform

I have a customer who delivered to us some data files. The customer works mainly on Linux, and there are some file names that differ only in case (upper/lower), e.g. `R40` and `r40` in the same folder. I've added them to my repository via a Linux machine, but now when I'm working with the repository on Windows, it says several of the files are missing, since Windows is case-insensitive for file names, and it can't have both `R40` and `r40` in the folder at the same time. This is preventing me from doing some SVN actions, like starting a merge. Obviously, I can't just change the names of their files and have their software still work, but we don't need the files when we're working on Windows.

Is there a way to get around this, while still having the customer's files in the repository for Linux checkouts? We just want them in the repository for convenience's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Windows clients can ignore whole directories and not specific files within directories you could create a Windows specific view on the repository using the [svn:externals property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).

Let’s say your repo looks like this:

```
/trunk/linux_and_windows_dir_1
/trunk/linux_only_dir_1
/trunk/linux_and_windows_dir_2
/trunk/linux_only_dir_2
...
```

You could create the following OS specific trunks:

```
/linux_trunk 
  svn:externals = 
    /trunk/linux_and_windows_dir_1
    /trunk/linux_only_dir_1
    /trunk/linux_and_windows_dir_2
    /trunk/linux_only_dir_2

/windows_trunk 
  svn:externals = 
    /trunk/linux_and_windows_dir_1
    /trunk/linux_and_windows_dir_2
```

Then have Lunux users check out and use linux_trunk. Windows users would checkout windows_trunk. Since both OS specific trunks only contains external definitions anything checked into them will automatically be checked into /trunk.

If a windows user checks a change into /windows_trunk/linux_and_windows_dir_1 
then that change will also be applied to /trunk/linux_and_windows_dir_1 and 
/linux_trunk/linux_and_windows_dir_1.

As I said, this only works if you specify the Windows specific parts of the repro using directories and not individual files.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I'm not sure how I could structure that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

No. I don't know any option or property to solve this problem directly with subversion. (The possible properties are listed [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.properties.html))

One possible workaround could be some "Client Side Hooks". (This is **not** a centralized operation by subversion itself and you need some access to each of these client windows machines)

If you are using the TortoiseSVN Client on Windows you can install a Client Side Hook and do "whatever" you want within this script. But keep in mind to setup the client side hook on every windows machine separately.

For more details about Client Side Hooks with TortoiseSVN see the docs of [TortoiseSVN (in the Chapter Client Side Hook Scripts)](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html).